# How to write a simple, type-erased composable iterator in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to write a simple composable Iterator that does not expose the internal type (so I can use one of these iterators in the interface and can realize different operations like concat, filter, ...). It's really intended to be simple but I'm currently stumbling over a simple compile error which I can't resolve

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN
#include "catch.hpp"

#include <functional>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct RangeIteratorData
{
    std::function<T&()> dereference;
    std::function<void()> increment;
};

template <typename T>
class RangeIterator
{
public:
    template <typename I>
    RangeIterator(I& iter)
    {
        auto dereference = [iter]() { return *iter; };
        auto increment = [iter]() -> void { ++iter; }; //here's the error
        m_data.dereference = dereference;
        m_data.increment = increment;
    }

    T& operator*();
    RangeIterator<T>& operator++();
private:
    RangeIteratorData<T> m_data;
};

template <typename T>
RangeIterator<T>& RangeIterator<T>::operator++()
{
    m_data.increment();
    return *this;
}

template <typename T>
T& RangeIterator<T>::operator*()
{
    return m_data.dereference();;
}

TEST_CASE("Wrap existing iterator in range iterator")
{
    std::vector<int> container{ 1,2,3 };
    RangeIterator<int> begin = RangeIterator<int>(container.begin());
    ++begin;
    REQUIRE(*begin == 1);
}
```

The error message is:

> Error C2678   binary '++': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::_Vector_iterator>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

I'm using VS2015. The code itself is far from complete but I don't get the meaning of this error message. I especially don't understand where the const comes from.

It would be nice if someone could point me in the correct location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
auto increment = [iter]() -> void { ++iter; };
```

Change this line to:

```
auto increment = [iter]() mutable -> void { ++iter; };
```

Without the `mutable`, the `operator()` member function of the lambda's type is `const`, so it can't modify the iterator.

Comment: Shouldn't the lambda capture iter by reference? Otherwise a copy is being modified instead of what was passed in

Comment: @Kevin I'm guessing that copying it by value is intended. In either case, either the capture is wrong or taking the iterator by non-const reference is wrong.

Comment: no. But it should make a copy on the heap. Something along ´I* iterator = new I(iter);´ and then using the pointer in the lambdas. But my experimental iterator is getting too large for my taste.